# vagrant up command error on sparkvn

Tags: vagrant

```
C:\Users\shubham\myvagrant>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'sparkvm' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> sparkvm: Box 'sparkmooc/base2' could not be found. Attempting to find and in
stall...
    sparkvm: Box Provider: virtualbox
    sparkvm: Box Version: >= 0
==> sparkvm: Loading metadata for box 'sparkmooc/base2'
    sparkvm: URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/sparkmooc/base2
The box 'sparkmooc/base2' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: https://atlas.hashicorp.com/sparkmooc/base2
Error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to atlas.hashicorp.com:443
```

Comment: Dumping stack trace (and not even formatting it properly) without giving us the details and describing what you tried so far to solve it is unlikely to get you any answers.

Comment: So far you just have a big error dump in your question. Could you edit it to include what you were doing to produce this error? And maybe what you've tried to do to resolve it so far?

Answer (score 2):

vagrant cannot download the box `sparkmooc/base2` from atlas due to SSL issue. You can do the following

```
$ vagrant box add sparkmooc/base2 --insecure
$ vagrant up
```